# Just after I ran windows update, Internet Explorer 9 and 11 won't open

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer

Just after I ran windows update, Internet Explorer won't open at all. I've ran virus scans (Hitman Pro) 10 plus times and I have installed the latest updates, we still get the same error message and IE won't open and IE11 won’t load

This is the error message

```
C:\windows\system32\api-ms-win-downlevel-shlwapi- I2-1-0.dll
```

OUR system -

```
Windows 7 64 bit operating System 
Internet Explorer 9 
I have restarted the PC
I have installed the latest updates
I have turned IE off & on several times
```

Could someone help us fix this issue?

Comment: Running the same virus scan over and over is going to produce the same results, over and over. Try a different scan if you honestly think Viruses are the issue. Otherwise, it's called Chome, FireFox, Opera, Chromium, etc... I'm honestly not interested in posting an answer if you're honestly still fighting to use Internet Explorer. IE is up to 11, not 9. So clearly you don't have all the updates. Unless you can't because your using Vista/XP, in which case the same still applies. You're OS is too outdated, and likely no longer supported. So it goes without saying that you should expect issues.

Comment: uninstall the latest IE Security update: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3058515 and look if the IE now works again.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [System Restore](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/features/system-restore) if you need IE that bad. The system settings are saved after each update, usually. You could then try to figure out which specific update caused a problem and research that or don't install it.

It would be simpler to try one of the browsers commented above.